# NavigatetoURL Visualforce page for Salesforce1

Tags: visualforce, salesforce1-app, url, navigation

Is there a blanket template covering the ability to create visualforce pages (containing navigatetoURL code) for internal company URLs that can be used on the Navigation tabs on Salesforce1?

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing that I know of to what you're looking for would be found in the Salesforce1 Mobile App Developer Guide under [Creating Visualforce Pages That Work in Mobile and Desktop](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce1.meta/salesforce1/vf_dev_best_practices_pages_multipurpose.htm).

Ideally, one uses Actions for navigation in Salesforce1, but if you're using Visualforce pages for both desktop and Salesforce1, you can include code that looks something like what's below:

```
// Go back to the Account detail page
if( (typeof sforce != 'undefined') && sforce && (!!sforce.one) ) {
    // Salesforce1 navigation
    sforce.one.navigateToSObject(aId);
}
else {
    // Set the window's URL using a Visualforce expression
    window.location.href = 
        '{!URLFOR($Action.Account.View, account.Id)}';
}
```

For more on this, also see [Navigation with the sforce.one Object](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce1.meta/salesforce1/salesforce1_dev_jsapi_sforce_one.htm) which includes information on the `sforce.one.navigateToURL(​url​[, isredirect])` function.

**Edit**

By "internal company URL", I assume you're referring to a link that's not within your Salesforce instance? If so, from the Docs:

> Relative and absolute URLs are supported. Relative URLs are relative to the one.app domain, and retain navigation history. External URLs—that is, URLs that are outside the Salesforce1 app—open in a separate browser window.

If you want to have support to browse to links that are outside the one.one app domain, but within your company's company's domain without leaving the app, you'd need to create a custom Salesforce Mobile App for your org using the Mobile APIs available to you. Otherwise, the standard Salesforce1 App will send your users to their default browser when you navigate them to a link that's outside the one.one app domain.

Comment: Thanks @crmprogdev (if it's an internal company URL, would plugging it in the URL in the URLFOR be sufficient?  I am simply looking to create a tab to be included on my navigation menu to bring me to the internal company website...my Visualforce option may be really basic.  Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

*e.force:navigateToURL* this method redirect you to your custom apex page within lightning experience.

*Your object after /apex/yourApexObject*

`"url": "/apex/yourApexObject"`

*You can add addition query in params eg:*

`"Id": dealId`

```
navigateToapexObject:  function(component, event) {
    var dealId = component.get("{!v.recordId}");
    $A.get("e.force:navigateToURL").setParams({
        "url": "/apex/yourApexObject=",
        "d": dealId
    }).fire();        
}
```

Comment: Add details why this code help to resolve the issue instead posting code alone

Comment: In my opinion you should add some explanation rather than sharing a code-snippet without any additional details.

Comment: @Reshma  I have update the code description. Let me know if this work